# kubectl get nodes not returning any result

Tags: azure, kubernetes

Issue: kubectl get nodes, returning an empty result

Cloud provider: Azure

K8s cluster built from scratch with VMSS instances/VMs

```
azureuser@khway-vms000000:~$ kubectl get no

No resources found in default namespace.
```

I am a bit stuck and do not know what else I could check to get to the bottom of this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you logged on to one of the nodes of the managed VMSS.

Instead do (e.g. from your dev machine):

```
az aks get-credentials --name MyManagedCluster --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az_aks_get_credentials

then you can run kubectl

Comment: oh wait, did you actually not use aks but built k8s yourself? that would raise the question, why? :)

Comment: Hi. Yes, indeed, I have built it from scratch using the kubernetes the hard way tutorial. I just wanna understand the magic under the hood. But it seems I don’t for now:)